# How to choose step size when using fixed step-size solver in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I wanna do a real-time simulation, if I wanna use the fixed step-size solver in Dymola, with different step sizes, the result could be a little bit different, so is there any standard procedure to choose the step size? Or do I have to do a lot of calculations to prove step size independence just like in the CFD area I need to prove grid independence?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if there is a standard procedure, but proving numerical stability is not straightforward for numerical solving of nonlinear/hybrid models. Therefore I would go with some not strictly mathematical procedure. As it seems you are free to chose the step-size, so I would do the following.

**Option 1** (with at least a little mathematical background):

- Linearize the model using the "Tools -> Linear Analysis -> Poles"
- The result is a plot containing the Eigenvalues and a table in the "Commands"-window. The latter should contain a column `freq. [Hz]` (Additional information can be generated by running a "Full Linear Analysis")
- Take the highest value for the frequency from the table and derive the necessary step-size for it, given the solvers properties (e.g. stability region)
- For Forward Euler it would make sense to use `StepSize = 1/max(freq) * 1/10`
- For others the relation can be very different, but for most explicit solvers, this should be a good starting point

Note: Probably other functions of the "Linear Analysis" contain useful information as well, so it is worth a try to run them.

The problem with the above method is, that the poles of a non-LTI system can depend on the inputs/states of the model. Therefore it can go wrong as the result depends on the state of the system or the time of linearization respectively.

**Option 2** (just go by trail and error):

Given you have a rough idea what the step-size should be you can do this:

- Pick a solver and select a rather small step-size. This should provide a good result but slow simulation (e.g. 100ns in your case).
- Then increase the step-size by e.g. a factor of 10, until the difference is getting to a level where you consider it too big to continue.
- Then reduce the changes in step-size to find a sweet-spot for the trade-off between performance and precision.

Note: The above steps could be the flipped, by starting with a big step-size and reducing it until the results match well enough.

**Validation/Finetuning**

To prove that the result of any of the two above options is not totally off, it would make sense do the following:

- Create a reference result with a proven well-working solver (in Dymola I would use DASSL with a reasonable relative tolerance).
- Double-check the reference result with a second solver, ideally something rather different (in Dymola this could be Radau, CVode is similar to DASSL)
- Compare the results of the reference solver with your fixed-step solver and check if you are fine with the difference.
- If the results are similar enough, you can try to increase the step-size to a point where the difference gets too big (finetuning)

**For both Options**

Note that when you change the system's properties (poles) or input the above procedure(s) should be repeated - at least the validation part.

Comment: By using option 1, I only get a plot with the title "Eigenvalues", where could I find the column `freq. [Hz]`?

Comment: I updated the answer - better late than never...